# Erro in npm run build

Tags: svelte, vite, npm-build

I am trying to use @vitejs/plugin-legacy in my Svelte project,but when I give the command npm run build, it gives this error:

```
[vite-plugin-svelte-kit] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\pedro\OneDrive\Documentos\digital_lock\digital_lock\.svelte-kit/output/client//manifest.json'
error during build:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\pedro\OneDrive\Documentos\digital_lock\digital_lock\.svelte-kit/output/client//manifest.json'
```

My vite.config.ts:

```
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import legacy from '@vitejs/plugin-legacy'

/** @type {import('vite').UserConfig} */
const config = {
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        legacy({
            targets: ['defaults', 'not IE 11']
          })
    ],
    server: {
        fs: {
            allow: ['..']
        }
    },
};

export default config;
```

I am trying to configure my application to work in older browser versions